# Use sql function for avoiding union all between the same query with different parameters values

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a query like this:

```
select VALUE from REVENUES WHERE categoryId == :x
```

Now, I execute more times this query using more values and merging all with union all

```
select categoryId, VALUE from REVENUES WHERE categoryId == 10
union all
select categoryId, VALUE from REVENUES WHERE categoryId == 100
union all
select categoryId, VALUE from REVENUES WHERE categoryId == 1000
```

Is it possible to define a function that receives categoryId as parameter and launch the query?

```
function myQuery (categoryId ) {
    select categoryId, VALUE from REVENUES WHERE categoryId == :x
}

myQuery(10)
union all
myQuery(100)
union all
myQuery(1000)
```

Is it possible to do a script like these, without re formatting de query with:

```
select categoryId, VALUE from REVENUES 
       WHERE categoryId == :x or categoryId == :y or categoryId == :z
```

Comment: why not use the `IN` predicate?  e.g. `where categoryId in (10, 100, 1000)` ,and you can parameterise the in-list also.

Answer (score 1):

use the IN predicate like this:

```sql
SELECT categoryId, value 
  FROM revenues 
 WHERE categoryId IN (10, 100, 1000);
```

If you don't know how to prepare the values at runtime you can denormalize them like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE validCategories (
  categoryId INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(categoryId)
);

SELECT categoryId, value 
  FROM revenues 
 WHERE categoryId IN ((SELECT * FROM validCategories));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an ability to dynamically construct your query, and you need to use some parameter as string of integer values, then I'd suggest you to create a generic "tokenizer" function like below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TOKENIZER (P_STR VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS TABLE (TOK INT)
RETURN 
SELECT V.TOK
FROM XMLTABLE 
(
'$doc/d/i'
PASSING XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT '<d><i>' || replace(P_STR, ',', '</i><i>') || '</i></d>') as "doc"
COLUMNS 
  TOK INT PATH '.'
) V;
```

You may use this function with different list of values:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(TOKENIZER('10, 100')) T;
SELECT * FROM TABLE(TOKENIZER('10, 100, 1000')) T;
```

Evey such a call returns a table with 1 INT column and the corresponding number of rows.
You may use it as follows:

```
select R.categoryId, R.VALUE 
from REVENUES R
JOIN TABLE(TOKENIZER('10, 100, 1000')) T ON T.TOK = R.categoryId;
```

You may use a parameter marker instead of the string constant '10, 100, 1000'.

Answer (score 0):

I use a `global temporary table` when a query has a variable number of values to select on. Load the temporary table with the list of values. Then use the `in` clause to select `where` a column is `in` the temporary table.

```
declare global temporary table  custCodeList ( 
custcode char(6)) with replace

insert into qtemp/custcodelist  ( custCode )   
values('GLLL01') 

insert into qtemp/custcodelist  ( custCode )   
values('BOFA01')
```

```
select   a.orhshpnam, a.orhdate, a.orhshpdate         
from     dwhpf30c a
where    a.orhcust in ( select  b.custcode 
                        from    qtemp/custCodeList b )
```

which is the same as selecting against a list of literal values:

```
select   a.orhshpnam, a.orhdate, a.orhshpdate 
from     dwhpf30c a
where    a.orhcust in ( 'GLLL01', 'BOFA01')
```